# C# FtpWebRequest downloaded FTP files are empty

Tags: c#, zip, ftpwebrequest

I have been working on a simple program to connect to FTP server and download a ZIP file. It makes the connection, authenticates and downloads the zip folder, but the contents are empty. I cant figure it out, please help! Thanks!

```
Console.WriteLine("downloading file . . . " + ary_connect[3]);

FtpWebRequest requestFileDownload = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ary_connect[0]);
requestFileDownload.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ary_connect[1], ary_connect[2]);
requestFileDownload.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
FtpWebResponse responseFileDownload = (FtpWebResponse)requestFileDownload.GetResponse();
            
byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
using (Stream input = responseFileDownload.GetResponseStream())
{
  using (FileStream output = new FileStream(ary_connect[4] + ary_connect[3], FileMode.Create))
    {
      int bytesRead;
      while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
      {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Post the content of that array, as readable strings: nobody knows what `ary_connect[0]` is or what `ary_connect[4] + ary_connect[3]` will be (of course the credentials are not useful).  -- You should check what is the `StatusCode` of `responseFileDownload` before you start writing something somewhere.

Comment: Also, specify whether `.EnableSsl = true;` is actually not needed and the .Net version in use.

Comment: Hey thanks Jimmy, the array stuff is just the various folder paths and user credentials, as i said it connects and authenticates and downloads and saves the appropriate zip folder in the correct local directory so I dont think there is a path or FTP credentials issue. Its just the ZIP cannot be opened I get "compressed folder is invalid" - I will add a check for the StatusCode - thanks again PS - also SSL is not an issue here - may add it later PSS - .NET 4.7.2

Comment: I know what the array stuff is, the content is unknown. Post that. -- What does *saves the appropriate zip folder* mean? You mean *saves the appropriate zip FILE*. Which doesn't look exactly *appropriate*. -- Also post the Status response from the Server. -- *SSL is not an issue here - may add it later* meaning? How you'll be adding it later? Is it your own Server? It doesn't use any TLS protocol?

Comment: Hey actually Jimmi you did help me get this - after you mentioned the arrays I took another look at my folder paths and was calling the wrong file - problem fixed - thanks!